# IF statement with Right, Len, and Concatenate

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, concatenation, formulas

I am using Google sheets and not sure why I can not get this to work but I think I have a bracket off or syntax not quite right.

I am trying to parse out a URL and get the last 3 letters to compare to in my IF statement. If the 3 letters match png then do something if not do another.

```
=IF(RIGHT(E2,LEN(E2)4)=".png",CONCATENATE(F2,G4), CONCATENATE(F2, G3))
```

The URL comes in through a formula into the cell E2 using this:

```
=ImportXML(B3, "//meta[@property='og:image']/@content")
```

I am not sure if that has something to do with it or not but I have found I need to test for .jpg and .png because not everyone uploads .jpg all the time causing things to break on my feed.

[Here is my google spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1__qAK5ZWUxdWktVBbSAaaFZcR94vlrFKsxUmeWc-wjM/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this will a regexmatch and regexreplace:

```
=if(REGEXMATCH(E2,"\.png"),REGEXREPLACE(E2,"\.png","-500x500.png"),REGEXREPLACE(E2,"\.jpg","-500x500.jpg"))
```

Basically it is checking for the `.png` like in your original formula - just a slightly shorter, easier way, if it is there, it automatically returns true, so then you can use regexreplace to swap it out for the extension you want, else swap out the jpg extension.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=IF(RIGHT(E2,4)=".png",CONCATENATE(F2,G4), CONCATENATE(F2, G3))
```

Comment: Thank you this formula worked to just like I was wanting it to but I went with Aurielle because it took care of having to Concatenate as well. Hate having to choose just one correct answer because you both had great answers and they both worked well. Thank you again.